# Access Geoserver from Amazon E2C from Internet

Tags: openlayers, web-hosting, geoserver

Need help accessing my GIS website on Amezon E2C through Internet.

I have Geoserver running on 8080 port on Amazon E2C VPC Windows 2008 Instance,and website using openlayer,geoext hosted through IIS on it, my E2C have private IP 10.#.#.70 which i use in openlayer code to refer to WMS layers as below.

```
       parcel_boundary = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "GEO:parcel_boundary", "http://10.#.#.70:8080/geoserver/GEO/wms",
                {
                    LAYERS: 'GEO:parcel_boundary',
                    STYLES: '',
                    format: 'image/png',
                    tiled: true,
                    tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    yx : {'EPSG:32643' : false}
                } 
            );
```

My E2C have Public IP 54.#.#.28 which i can use to access my website through internet using url http://54.#.#.28/WEBGIS/GIS/GIS.html, but i can only view the Html & Geoext part of website with Blank Map, Actually WMS request to Geoserver is http://10.#.#.70:8080/geoserver/GEO/wms which donot fetch any valid data from internet. but on E2C server
i can view Site properly with Map using same Url.

What changes should i do to view Wms Layers in my Website through internet url. 
if i need proxy how to set it.  Pls Help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Help..

Problem resolved, it was my Server Firewall Issue on EC2. i allowed both Inbound & Outbound Exception for port 8080 and now i can easily access my url through internet. :)

Steps to configuring firewall Rules if needed in below URL.
ttp://www.2x.com/blog/2010/04/tech/configuring-the-windows-server-2008-r2-firewall-to-open-ports-for-2x-solutions/

Answer (score 0):

Your openlayers map connects from client browser to the geoserver, which means your private EC2 IP is hidden from the clients browser trying to access map data. You have to make the geoserver publicly available on the internet (as your website) for it to work - and then use your public IP to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I use IIS URL rewrite for the same scenario.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

http://forums.iis.net/t/1189344.aspx/1